# Hostname no longer accessible after VM migration to new host

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, hostname, server-message-block, veeam

We have a fileserver that was on a dying ESXi host, I migrated it to the new one with Veeam (Couldn't use vCenter until I upgrade the ESXi hosts to 5.5). Once I booted it back up, everything acts normally except I can't access it through SMB

```
\\MY-SVR
```

I can get to it with:

```
\\192.168.2.9
```

I can also ping the hostname and nslookup of the hostname resolves with no problems, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: The server is Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2, it is domain joined, no other PCs or servers on the domain have this issue.

Comment: Check your DNS configuration.
Name resolution for file sharing are goes via DNS or WINS
If one of them is not configure well you will not found your server.
two more questions for you, is your server get its IP address by DHCP?
Did you registered your "new server" to the DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what caused it, but by

1. Rebooting MY-SVR
2. Navigating to share via IP
3. Renavigating to share by hostname

It resolved.